# single textfield name for different views in iPad

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiview

I use 2 different UIView for landscape and portrait. One for landscape and one for portrait view.I have textfields and buttons. I am using same name and methods for the buttons which are in landscape and portrait.
But my textfield is working only at landscape or only at portrait.Not both. What is the reason?
How can I solve my problem?

Comment: You have 21 questions and 0 accepted question. Increase please your rate to attract attention (by clicking on the ✓ sign left to the answer)

Comment: I use different views in landscape and portrait. I use buttons and textfield in both views with same name. Is it possible to work the textfield with same name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you creating your views using nib files or programmatically?

You cannot bind two different views to the same IBOutlet/property. You should probably create two properties called textfieldLandscape and textfieldPortrait, that way they should both work.